# Phonegap on Windows 7 - Installation issues

Tags: cordova

I´m new to phonegap and i´m trying to install it on Windows 7.

I installed nodejs and then phonegap. After that, I enter the following command "phonegap create HelloWorld" from phonegap\bin directory as instructed on phonegap homepage.

After that, the following file is created with the information below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/*!
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var CLI = require('../lib/cli');

/*!
 * Run the command-line client.
 */

var cli = new CLI().argv(process.argv);
```

I tried clone phonegap from github but the same occurs.

What does it means ?
What I am missing to install?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how to use Phonegap so i just can tell you, how to use Cordova.

Look at this [Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface). It explains you, how to set up the Cordova Environment which you can work with. After that you scroll down a bit. There you can find a detailed explanation of how to create a Cordova Project.

Maybe you try this.

Comment: thanks a lot.
But im now using phonegap build. In this way i can just focus on folder www and send it to phongap build to compile.  tks anyway